# "conversion to non-scalar type requested" Error in this small code snippet

Tags: c, multithreading

Here is my code snippet, while trying to compile this its showing "conversion to non-scalar type requested" error at line "**tid[i] = (pthread_t) -1**" which is highlighted below. Please help me if anyone knows about this.

```
main(void)
{    
unsigned int i, repeat;
unsigned int num_threads = sizeof(testfiles) / sizeof(testfiles[0]);
void *results[MAX_ARGC];
int ret;

xmlInitParser();
for (repeat = 0;repeat < 500;repeat++) {
xmlLoadCatalog(catalog);

for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    results[i] = NULL;
    **tid[i] = (pthread_t) -1;**  //getting error at this point
}
```

thanks in advance,

Sri

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to show us tid's declariation. It might matter.

Comment: Why have you some `**` after the semicolumn on the line with problem ?

Comment: @Cédric Julien, he's (unfortunately) using ths stars to identify the problem line. Those aren't in his code.

Answer (score 1):

Erm.... I'm mainly missing the include for pthread_t

```
#inlcude <pthread.h>
```

Otherwise, I'm pretty sure it is with the (not shown) definition of `tid`